# Warning: include(xxxx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, composer-php, ezpdf

I'm having a problem regarding using composer with ros/ezpdf

This is my file structure

```
home
    --miga
            --db
                --file.php
            --vendor
                --ros
                    --ezpdf
                        --src
                            --Cezpdf.php
        composer.json
```

in my main file i have this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once "dbconfig.php";
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include '../vendor/ros/ezpdf/src/Cezpdf.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_PT');
```

and my composer.json this:

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": ["db/class.esmaior.php"],
  "files": ["src/Cpdf.php", "src/Cezpdf.php"]

},
"require": {
  "phpmailer/phpmailer": "6.0.x-dev",
  "ros/ezpdf": "0.12.1"
}
```

If i use this

```
include '../vendor/ros/ezpdf/src/Cezpdf.php';
```

The pdf is created but in every pages of my website i have those warnings

```
Warning: include(../vendor/ros/ezpdf/src/Cpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

and if i remove the line i have this error

Fatal error: Class 'Cezpdf' not found in /home/xxxx/public_html/miga/db/class.esmaior.php on line 2910

Comment: When using autoload, you shouldn't use require for each class. Autoload should do this for you. https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: i i don't use require...Fatal error: Class 'Cezpdf' not found in /home/xxxx/public_html/miga/db/class.esmaior.php on line 2910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `include(__DIR__."/../vendor/ros/ezpdf/src/Cezpdf.php");`